# PySpark.RDD.first -> UnpicklingError: NEWOBJ class argument has NULL tp_new

Tags: pyspark

I use python 2.7 with spark 1.5.1 and I get this:

```
df = sqlContext.read.parquet(".....").cache()
df = df.filter(df.foo == 1).select("a","b","c")
def myfun (row):
    return pyspark.sql.Row(....)
rdd = df.map(myfun).cache()
rdd.first()
==> UnpicklingError: NEWOBJ class argument has NULL tp_new
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as usual, the pickling error boiled down to `myfun` being closed over an unpicklable object.

as usual, the solution is to use `mapPartitions`:

```
import pygeoip
def get_geo (rows):
    db = pygeoip.GeoIP("/usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIPCity.dat")
    for row in rows:
        d = row.asDict()
        d["new"] = db.record_by_addr(row.client_ip) if row.client_ip else "noIP"
        yield d
rdd.mapPartitions(get_geo)
```

instead of `map`:

```
import pygeoip
db = pygeoip.GeoIP("/usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIPCity.dat")
def get_geo (row):
    d = row.asDict()
    d["new"] = db.record_by_addr(row.client_ip) if row.client_ip else "noIP"
    return d
rdd.map(get_geo)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do but maybe:

```
rdd =  df.rdd.cache()
rdd.first()
```

.rdd transforms DataFrame to rdd